# Import a specific macro from a module in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I import the json module just to use its useful [`%*` macro](https://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#%25%2A.m%2Cuntyped):

```
import json        # for %*
let json_payload = $(%* {"username": "admin", "password": "1234"})
```

Is it possible to import just this particular macro from the module? Something like this (though obviously this doesn't work):

```
from json import %*
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can absolutely do that, but for operators you need to surround them with backticks.  you are also using `$` from `json` so you need to import that too:

```
from json import `%*`,`$`
let json_payload = $(%* {"username": "admin", "password": "1234"})
echo json_payload #{"username":"admin","password":"1234"}
```